# How to execute some jQuery or JavaScript code after a redirect has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

How can I execute jQuery/JS code as soon as a jQuery/JS redirect like...

```
$(location).attr('href','/target_path');
```

...or...

```
window.location.href = "/target_path";
```

...has finished loading the new page?

Specifically, I need to pass an alert message and insert it into and display it (enclosed in some HTML) on the new page.

Comment: Why not use the onload callback function inside the new page?

Comment: You need to pass the information to the new page using a querystring or cookie.

Comment: you could just put the code in the standard DOM ready $() handler for the new page

Comment: Adding to what @Slaks suggested, hashes could be another option. Pass in a short hash, then on the new page, depending on what `location.hash` is, show the corresponding alert message. There're many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to tell JavaScript to execute some code after a redirect.

However you have different options:

1. Pass a string in the redirect URL and then do something on "ready"
2. Store some information in a cookie and then do something on "ready"
3. Store some data using [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) (namely `sessionStorage`) if you don't mind the smaller browser support

Comment: but how would I know when I should access these data in sessionStorage? I need to know when I am on next page, some code will be executed which will get data from sessionStorage.

Comment: @MuhammadUzair store something in DOM Storage before the redirect and then check on page load if the data is there.

Comment: well we can store code in sessionStorage or localStorage but when we should get back to our code & execute it, we would never know when redirect is completed.

Comment: It's impossible to execute code after a redirect in the same context/page, because a redirect makes you leave the context/page. Nowadays, we have a lot more modern solutions where a redirect is not necessary at all, with page routing, content rehydration etc.. So this approach is flawed to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Once the redirect happens you are no longer on that page. You can't execute code on a page you are no longer on. If you want the next page to do something then you need to pass, either by cookie or URL parameter, a flag that instructs it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the page that's redirecting. You can read the referrer in the landing page (`document.referrer`), and then decide whether to display an alert based on that, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "It's some text";
var loc = '/target_path';

loc += '?message=' + encodeURI(x);
```

The JS file on the new page can then look at the query string to see if a message is there, and do the required action if it's detected.

You can use `window.location.search` on the new page to see what's there, although I'd recommend hunting for a deparam function in a library to turn the query string into a more usable object.