# How to execute jQuery after redirect?

Tags: jquery, redirect

I wish to execute jQuery after a redirect:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
  window.location.href = "/test/blabla";
  alert("test");
}
```

I've googled and found that this is not possible to do because once the redirect happens you are no longer on that page. But can someone please give me an example of an alternative.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
The page i'm redirecting to has checkboxes that are all default checked. When I click on the link I want to uncheck a few of the checkboxes, it depends of parameters that i get from the first page.

Comment: why dont you execute that code first and redirect afterwords....

Comment: I want to eat dinner after I go to sleep, but I can't chew without being awake. Please give me an example of an alternative.

Comment: the redirection occurs before or after the jQuery instructions? Your title mismatch your question.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I want to execute the code on the page that i redirect to, not on the page where the link is

Comment: Impossible!!! You cant. Visit the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342028/how-to-execute-some-jquery-or-javacript-code-after-a-redirect-has-completed

Comment: @nicolallias Damn, big typo, you're right

Comment: @user2401175 I've seen that link, but i can't find a clear workaround

Comment: @MichielG then put your code in the page your redirecting to?

Comment: As much as I absolutely HATE using iframes, this _might_ be a situation where you want to use them. Instead of doing a full-page redirect, you could consider loading the new page in an iframe, and then firing your javascript from the main/parent window. Aside from that, what you're asking simply cannot be done. Of course, this is assuming that you are not the owner of the second page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately you can not. after redirecting, you are no longer on that page. You can't execute code on a page you are no longer on.

If you want the next page to do something then you need to pass a flag that instructs it to do so using:

1) either by cookie or

2) URL parameter

Comment: Provide an example please, this answer is a copy paste from the link above

Comment: @MichielG : so you want every thing ready made.... why don't you give it a try. try creating two fiddle and then redirect from one to another.

Comment: @MichielG Let me try again; you question is basically this - "My body was vaporized by a laser, how will I get to work tomorrow?" - You can't. Your gone. Your page is gone. Your javascript engine is gone. The best you can do is signal to the next page for it to take some step in your place.

Answer (score 3):

You can add hash to url like:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
  window.location.href = "/test/blabla#execute";
}
```

and on page **blabla** you can check your hash:

```
if (window.location.hash === '#execute') {
  alert("test");
}
```